# i want to remove woocommerce_order_item_visible

Tags: woocommerce

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PV9sJ.jpg)

I want to remove the given image product variable area to be remove which code should I use in product order details file in woo commerce plugin.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question lacks information to get any help from [so] users. Please take the [tour], and read through the [help], learn  [ask] a good question? to maximize your chance to get answer to your questions. If you run into a specific problem and if you're stuck, send a description of the problem, including a [mcve] and people will be very glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function alter_woocommerce_order_item_name($name, $item, $is_visible) {

        if (isset($item['product_id'])) {
            $product_id = $item['product_id'];
            $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
            $product_permalink = $product->get_permalink();
            $name = $product_permalink ? sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $product_permalink, $product->get_name()) : $product->get_name();
        }

        return $name;
    }

add_filter('woocommerce_order_item_name', 'alter_woocommerce_order_item_name', 10, 3);
```

Add this code into your active theme `functions.php` file

Comment: I tried but didn't workout

Comment: Try `echo $product->get_name(); exit;` inside the if after `$product` - Whats the output